# Как удалить часть строки зная индекс начала и конца части?

Tags: c#

Мне нужен код, где я сам ввожу строку, после этого (на следующей строке) я ввожу два числа через пробел, а на третьей должна выводиться изменённая строка.

В этой строке не должно быть символов, индекс которых был записан во второй строке двумя числами (первое число - это первый индекс удаленного символа, а второе - конец удаленной части и последний символ, который нужно удалить). То есть, то, что находится между индексами, тоже должно быть удаленно.

Вот максимум, что я смог сделать:

```cs
string str = Console.ReadLine();
int num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
str = str.Replace(str[num1-1], '#');
str = str.Replace(str[num2-1], '#');
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write(str[i]);
}
```

1. Как мне записать два числа в одну строку через пробел?
2. Как мне удалить эту часть строки(символы от первого индекса к второму)?

**Пример, что должно получиться:**

```
Ввод: Press any key
Ввод: 7 10
Вывод: Press key
```

Comment: `string text = Console.ReadLine(); string[] tokens = Console.ReadLine().Split(); int num1 = int.Parse(tokens[0]); int num2 = int.Parse(tokens[1]); Console.WriteLine(text.Remove(num1) + text.Substring(num2));` сложно?

Comment: @aepot Нет, огромное спасибо! Только можно хоть как то уменьшить память, которую занимает код?

Comment: Ничего не понял

Comment: @aepot это наверное какае-то олимпиадная задачка и у него решение в ограничение по памяти не укладывается

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = Console.ReadLine();

var nums = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();

str = str.Remove(nums[0], nums[1] - nums[0] );

Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```
//Ввод
string txt = Console.ReadLine();
string s = Console.ReadLine();

//Определяем границы удаления
int n = Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(' '))) - 1;
s = s.Remove(0, s.IndexOf(' '));
int k = Convert.ToInt32(s) - n;

//Удаляем
txt = txt.Remove(n, k);

//Вывод
Console.WriteLine("\n{0}", txt);
```

Comment: чтобы считать несколько чисел из одной строки лучше подойдёт `.Split()` или `.Split().Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray()`, это будет гораздо читабельнее и понятно